# propper SQL results parsing java

Tags: java, hashmap

i recently swapped over from python to java to extend my knowledge of java a bit, now i wanted to create a simpel DB wrapper all done, but i find my result parsing a bit extensive for what it is, is there a more proper way to make a list with this structure: result_index -> column_key/object
thanks already

also this is what i currently have:

```
    // public cause i use instance getter
    public HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> getResults() {
        try {
            // make collective set.
            HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> result_set = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>>();
            while(results.next()) { // loop through each result group

                // make current set / add all items to current set.
                HashMap<String, Object> current_set = new HashMap<String, Object>();      
                for(int x = 1; x < results.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); x++) {
                    current_set.put(results.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(x), results.getObject(x));
                }
                // add current set to collective set
                result_set.put(result_set.size(), current_set);
            }
            return result_set;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Change to `x <=`

Comment: In Java, you usually don't use interfaces with their implementing type but rather with their interface as type to keep the implementation of the interface exchangeable.

Comment: Never ignore exceptions the way you do here. Logging and continuing as-if nothing went wrong, is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ andreas why x <=? 
& im still scratching havent started at exception handeling.

Comment: What @maio290 meant, is that you should change return type to `Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>>`, so that method could change to e.g. `TreeMap` without affecting caller, if it wanted to.

Comment: @PythonNoob Because loop is `1..n` instead of the usual `0..(n-1)`.

Comment: *"havent started at exception handeling"* Then just add `throws SQLException` to your method and remove the `try-catch` from the code.

Comment: *Hint:* It would be nice for humans reviewing the returned data, if the inner map is a `LinkedHashMap`, so the column order is retained, and for the outer map to be a `TreeMap` or `LinkedHashMap`, so the row order is enforced / retained.

Comment: @Andreas will look into mapping/exception handeling some more :) only started again in java since today so all tips are welcome :)
Also LOVE that linkedHash / (treemap/linkedhash) solution